# IBM Worklight 6.1 - When changing Worklight preferences, I keep getting asked to "choose deployment target"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

In Worklight 6.1, when changing a preference in `Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Worklight`, then after clicking ok there is a pop up message "Please choose your deployment target".

But the changes on the preferences are not related to deployment target at all, rather to application center credentials or browser set up. When this dialog is shown, the OK button is disabled.

Just wondering what this deployment target is. It is annoying to have this popped up every time to change the preferences. Thanks.

Comment: Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it seems to happen **only** if navigating to `Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Worklight > IBM Mobile Application Platform Pattern`.

- If I will not navigate to this specific entry, then I won't get the dialog you are referring to.
- If I do navigate to it, then no matter which entry you'll visit next, you will always get the dialog.

In any case, it looks like a defect; it will be investigated. Thanks.

As for a workaround if you accidently clicked on that entry, you can:

- Choose some other entry from the preferences
- Just click `ESC`

Now when you enter the preferences again, you won't be in that erroneous preference entry.